# Swiftでトラッキングコードをどこからでも呼ばれる場所に設置したい

Tags: swift, ios

GAのスクリーントラッキングコードを、各ビューごとではなく、ビューを表示すると必ず呼ばれる（たとえばUIVeiwController）場所に設置し、動的にクラス名が取得できるようにしたいと考えていますが、実際にはどこにコードを設置するのが正しいのでしょうか？

できればサンプルとなるようなコードを提示していただけると助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 現在はどこに設置しているのでしょうか。標準的なケースではビューコントローラの`viewWillAppear`にトラッキングコードを記述します。 - 根拠: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift&hl=ja

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
現在は各ビューコントローラーにてviewDidAppearをオーバーライドして設置しています。
この場合、ビューコントローラーが増えると管理が煩雑になってしまうと思いまして、親クラスを拡張（extension UIViewController）してどうにか実現できないかと考えています。

Comment: エクステンションはオーバーライドに使えないのでこの問題の助けにならないかもしれません。メソッドをオーバーライドすることなくフックして処理を挟むAOPライブラリに`MOAspects`（https://github.com/moaible/MOAspects）などがあるのですが、開発が止まっているので現在のSwiftに未対応かもしれません。が、欲しい機能はこういうことですよね？

Comment: まさにこのような機能です。
Method Swizzlingという手法もあるみたいですが、副作用の影響範囲がまったく読めないので、いまのプロジェクトに採用は難しそうです。

Comment: Aspects https://github.com/steipete/Aspects であれば現在担当プロジェクトで利用しています。が、利用はObjective-Cのコードから行っているので、Swiftから呼べるかは分かりません。プロジェクト自体はSwift/Objective-Cが混在しています。

Comment: また、AOPライブラリは基本的にMethod Swizzlingによって実現されているので、Method Swizzlingをさけるのでしたら利用されない方が良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

親クラスを一つ作って他はそれを継承させるという方法でいかがでしょうか

```
class MYBaseViewController : UIViewController 
{
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) 
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // GAのスクリーントラッキングコードをここに記述
    }
}
```

各クラスでは以下のようにします。

```
class MYViewController : MYBaseViewController 
{
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) 
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)//これを忘れないこと。

        //通常通りのコードを記述
    }
}
```

extensionで実装すると、メソッドの追加という形になると思いますので、
手動で呼び出さなければならないことには変わりないと思います。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。
この方法も思いつきましたが、結局のところ数十個あるビューの継承先を変更しなければならず採用を見送っていましたが、今のところこのやり方がシンプルで影響範囲が少なそうです。